# How to pass value from the back-end to the front-end

Tags: javascript, node.js

as shown in the below posted code, i am trying to pass the value `access_token` from `fetchAuthenticationToken` to the method `fetch` in `Ws.js`.
in `fetchAuthenticationToken` i receive value for the `access_token` and then i set that value to both of `resolve` and `onResult`. up to here, i can get the value of `access_token` . the `.then()` of `processor` web-service.

in `processor` web-service, i call `.then(resp => {res.send(resp);})` so to send the value of `access_token` to the front-end. but the `console.info` of `fetch` displays the following:

```
{"msg":"I.xx::fetch:http://localhost:3000/xx/processor/","response":{}}
```

which as shown is an empty `response`

please let me know what i have missed and how to pass the value of `access_token` from the back-end to the front-end, from `fetchAuthenticationToken` to `fetch`

**setup.js**:

```
fetchAuthenticationToken(onResult) {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        this.#instance.post("/xx/xx/xx/xx/xx-xx/xx", this.#body, this.#config)
        .then(resp => {
            this.#access_token = resp.data.access_token;
            Object.assign(this.#instance.defaults, {headers: {authorization: `Bearer ${resp.data.access_token}`}})
            resolve(this.#access_token);
            onResult(this.#access_token);
        })
    });
}
```

**routes.js**:

```
router.post('/processor', async (req, res, next) => {
        let accessToken = null;
        const setup = new Setup();
        await setup.fetchAuthenticationToken((result) => {
            accessToken = result;
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-protobuf'); 
        })
        .then(resp => {
            res.send(resp);
        })
    });
```

**front-end Ws**:

```
fetch(onResult) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const ws = endPointsURLs.VUE_NEWSWM_APP_LOCAL_HOST_3000.description + endPointsURLs.VUE_NEWSWM_APP_PATH.description + BackendWssConstants.CONST_WS_SENTINELHUB_ENGINE_PROCESSOR.description;
        fetch(ws, this.#requestOptions)
        .then(response => {
            this.#msg = JSON.stringify({msg:infoTag + 'fetch:' + ws, response: response});
            console.info(this.#msg);
            resolve(response);
            onResult(response);
        })
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response param you get back from fetch is not the json itself. You need to call `text()` on it first:

```
fetch(onResult) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const ws = endPointsURLs.VUE_NEWSWM_APP_LOCAL_HOST_3000.description + endPointsURLs.VUE_NEWSWM_APP_PATH.description + BackendWssConstants.CONST_WS_SENTINELHUB_ENGINE_PROCESSOR.description;
        fetch(ws, this.#requestOptions)
        .then(response=>response.text())
        .then(response => {
            this.#msg = JSON.stringify({msg:infoTag + 'fetch:' + ws, response: response});
            console.info(this.#msg);
            resolve(response);
            onResult(response);
        })
    });
}
```

You can simplify your code further. In fetchAuthenticationToken it looks like post() is already returning a promise so you don't need to wrap it in another promise. This is a simpler version of it:

```
fetchAuthenticationToken() {
    return  this.#instance.post("/xx/xx/xx/xx/xx-xx/xx", this.#body, this.#config)
      .then(resp => {
        this.#access_token = resp.data.access_token;
        Object.assign(this.#instance.defaults, {headers: {authorization: `Bearer ${resp.data.access_token}`}})
        return this.#access_token;
        
    })
}

router.post('/processor', async (req, res, next) => {
    let accessToken = null;
    const setup = new Setup();
    await setup.fetchAuthenticationToken()
        .then(resp => {
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-protobuf'); 
        res.send(resp);
     })
});
```

Easier to debug by removing unnecessary layers.

Comment: but what if i want to wrap `fetchAuthenticationToken` around a promise as in my question, what would be changed please?i just curious to know please

Comment: Are you positive `resp.data.access_token` is the correct value?

Comment: yes, using the code i posted, i get the authentication token,

Comment: Updated the answer (issue with FE code)

Comment: thanks for your answer, but calling `.text()` solved the issue. when i call `.json()` nothing changes. would you please modify your answer if that make sense to you?!

Comment: Sure, that's fine. You probably want to make your api use a json content type (application/json) and send some valid json data though, it's easier to deal with on both end